# Use xdotool in a telnet session

Tags: shell-script, scripting, process

I have to simulate key presses in a telnet session, and everything has to be invoked by a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh    
telnet 192.168.1.14 50000 
xdotool type "404"
```

However, once the telnet session takes place, it has to end before the xdotool is actually executed. Is there a way to the key simulation while telnet is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script did it for me.

```
#!/bin/sh    
gnome-terminal --title="Telnet" -x telnet 192.168.1.14 50000 
WID=`xdotool search --class "Telnet" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool type "404"
xdotool key "KP_Enter"
```

It creates a telnet session in a new window titled "Telnet". The `xdotool search` finds that window and focuses in it after which `xdotool type` is used to simulate the press buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Process-control commands such as `nohup` and `disown` make it easy for you to start long-running processes and keep them running even after you log out/end your session.

> When you run a shell session, all the processes you run at the command line are child processes of that shell. If you log out or your session crashes or otherwise ends unexpectedly, SIGHUP (signal to hang up) kill signals will be sent to its child processes to end them too.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts) will answer, how to execute a script/commands after telneting.